# Extract the hostname of an URL

Tags: subdomain, url

Is there any standarized or widely used method to extract something like a 'top level host name' from an URL?

For example, for `http://images.google.com` I like to have `google.com` (even if `images.` connects a different server als `http://google.com` would), whereas `http://www.amazon.co.uk` should give `amazon.co.uk`.

So I like to get the hostname with any subdomain removed.

Comment: This would be fairly easy by getting first a list of known TLD, and writing a very simple perl script doing a substitution on the string removing all but "domain.TLD"...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  For more information see [How do I ask a good question](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask).  Are you wanting to do a rewrite for YOUR site or what exactly are you trying to accomplish with the info?

Comment: @Kwaio this won't work as some countries issue second level domains, like `.co.uk` that can't be distinguished from a host named `co` without the knowledge of the UK's specific second level domain rules. And UK is only one of the many countries... so the question would be where to get such a list in a standarized way..

Comment: @TheCleaner: I like to get 'sites' for statistical purposes, so I like to group all Google services on google.com but obviusly not group all hosts ending in `.co.uk`.

Comment: Without standardized list of TLDs, you would have to build complex heuristics which would try to regroup similar domains... I definitly don't see another way...

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla maintains a compiled list of second level domain restrictions.

Description: http://publicsuffix.org/learn/

The list: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/test/unit/data/test_psl.txt?raw=1

This list could be parsed and the rules derived could be used to detect if the second level domain is a restricted one and thus the host name includes the third level domain.